# SWT plugin missing from 64 bit RCP build

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have set up a headless build environment to build our RCP products for windows 32 and 64 bit. My problem is that the 64 bit build is missing the SWT plugin and the application will not start until I manually copy in the SWT plugin.

In the log files this exception can be found:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError`

Looking in the plugin directory of the 64 bit build I found `org.eclipse.swt_3.6.2.v3659c.jar` which does not contain any class files but only the manifest and some about files.
To properly make use of SWT, another plugin must also be present in the plugin directory - `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.2.v3659c.jar`
This plugin contains the 64 bit specific code and/or resources.
The 32 bit version of this plugin is added to the 32 bit build, but not to the 64 bit.
So the question now is - Why not?

Comment: Very hard to say anything with so little information. Do you have the RCP delta pack installed in the target platform so that all the platform specific versions of SWT are available?

Comment: Yes. I have installed both the 32 and 64 bit version (org.eclipse.swt_3.6.2.v3659c).

Comment: Did you set the Architecture to be 64 bit? In your target platform (Preferences -> Target Platform- > Edit -> Environment) or build process to os=win32, ws=win32, arch=x86_64?

Comment: I build headlessly. I tried setting the basearch=x86_64 and also baseos and basews (win64). But it did not work.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022600/cannot-load-64-bit-swt-libraries-on-32-bit-jvm-replacing-swt-file

Comment: THanks for your input @GuyT, but your link does not cover my problem. This is a headless build problem.

Comment: @vio: ws=win64 will not work. Even for 64bit you have to set it to win32, and only the arch has to be x86_64.