# Can you mix a target platform with both 32 and 64 bit plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, rcp

I have mixed 32 bit and 64 bit plugins with my delta pack to build RCP plugins and products headlessly. Can the PDE build distinguish between platform dependent plugins all the time?
Any thoughts are welcome.
Also feel free to correct any misused terminology.

Comment: There is no problem having the delta pack installed in your target platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

(This sentence added to satisfy Stackoverflow minimal post length).

Comment: Would you mind also having a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979924/swt-plugin-missing-from-64-bit-rcp-build