# Eclipse Won't Start - JVM incompatibility

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to open my Eclipse - and nothing happens, no window is opening.
this is the warnings I got in D:\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\configuration\1424604493775.log

I understand that my JVM is incompatible with my version - but how do i fix it?
Thank you!

```
!SESSION 2015-02-22 13:28:12.975 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=iw_IL
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-22 13:28:17.107
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 32 bit JVM and 64 bit Eclipse. These should match, so download a 32 bit Eclipse or a 64 bit JVM.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are running on Win 64-bit.

First, install latest **JDK 8** (64-bit) available thru java.com

Go to Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings

Then Advanced Tab ->Environment Variables

System Variables on the bottom

Click New...

Add variable name `JAVA_HOME`

Add value `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\`  (should be this by default, check yours)

Click New...

Add variable name `JRE_HOME`

Add value `c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\`  (check your path)

Then select 'Path' variable in the list, click Edit...

Add to the end of string `;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\;`

That's all.

Please, reboot for now.

In command prompt make sure you can run commands:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Answer (score -1):

your problem is: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
first google result is:
[Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM ( replacing SWT file )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022600/cannot-load-64-bit-swt-libraries-on-32-bit-jvm-replacing-swt-file)

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, please flag to close it as such.