# Eclipse crashes when I try and open it and displays an error message

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, crash-reports, eclipse-indigo

Whenever I try and open eclipse it says 
Error:could not create the java virtual machine Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Here is the log

```
    !SESSION 2015-06-20 23:33:01.643 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.8.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-20 23:33:06.523
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: [Google search on this error](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=eclipse+unsatisfiedlinkerror+cannot+load+64-bit+swt)

Comment: [Similar question on this own site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022600/cannot-load-64-bit-swt-libraries-on-32-bit-jvm-replacing-swt-file). Please do consider searching on such problems before coming here, or if you do, show your links and explain how they don't help you with your particular case.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I cant even get into the eclipse menu so that wont work

Comment: Sure it will help -- you may need to re-install Eclipse, but first install the correct bit version of Java, and then install the matching bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have both the matching versions and im still getting it.