# Embed Youtube Video in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, video, youtube, embed

I have following problem:

I try to embed a YT video in my Java Swing. Therefore I installed DJProject from this website https://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject/?source=typ_redirect

I added following external JAR's:
sw-4.3-win32-x86.jar
DJNativeSwing.jar
DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar

But I get this exception message:

```
NativeSwing[1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
NativeSwing[1]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[1]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[1]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[1]:     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[1]:     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
NativeSwing[1]:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[1]:     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[1]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.runNativeSide(SWTNativeInterface.java:1273)
NativeSwing[1]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.main_(SWTNativeInterface.java:1461)
NativeSwing[1]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.main(NativeInterface.java:224)
NativeSwing[2]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
NativeSwing[2]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[2]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[2]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[2]:     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[2]:     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
NativeSwing[2]:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[2]:     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[2]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.runNativeSide(SWTNativeInterface.java:1273)
NativeSwing[2]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.main_(SWTNativeInterface.java:1461)
NativeSwing[2]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.main(NativeInterface.java:224)
NativeSwing[3]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
NativeSwing[3]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[3]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[3]:     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[3]:     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[3]:     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
NativeSwing[3]:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[3]:     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
NativeSwing[3]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.runNativeSide(SWTNativeInterface.java:1273)
NativeSwing[3]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.main_(SWTNativeInterface.java:1461)
NativeSwing[3]:     at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.main(NativeInterface.java:224)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.openChannel(OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:67)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.initialize(MessagingInterface.java:57)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.<init>(OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:32)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface$SwingOutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.<init>(OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:162)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.createOutProcessMessagingInterface(SWTNativeInterface.java:1072)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.createOutProcessCommunicationChannel(SWTNativeInterface.java:811)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.open_(SWTNativeInterface.java:342)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.open(NativeInterface.java:100)
    at tatil.main.main(main.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.openChannel(OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:65)
    ... 8 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your jar is 32-bit but your JVM is 64-bit. It basically tells you exactly in the error message.

Comment: "Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM" => What is unclear about that?

Comment: Just reinstall JDK with 32 Bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly shown in exception message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load
>   32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Install 32 Bit JDK as 32-bit SWT libraries cannot run with 64 bit run-time.

Download x84 from the following link, Remove existing java installation and install the one downloaded.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Or check this

> [SWT on Windows 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921193/swt-on-windows-64-bit)

Comment: Thank you very much. I overlooked the part of the Exception message